# Rendering an active menu element in a menu partial in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, menu, partials

I have a dynamic submenu that is rendered according to which page the user is on. I placed the following code in a _sub_menu.html.erb partial:

```
<a href="/dashboard/index" class="current">Index</a>
<a href="/dashboard/account">Account</a>
<a href="/dashboard/payments">Payments</a>`
```

From my my main view, I call `<%= render 'sub_menu' %>`, which works.

However, I want to change the class="current" part according to which page the user is on. I was hoping to do this from the render by passing in a local parameter and rendering according to that, but it seems hacky:

`<%= render 'sub_menu' , :locals => {:active_item => 'payments'}  %>`

Plus the logic becomes really ugly. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make use of the block parameter to [`link_to_unless_current`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_unless_current), which provides the content to render when the link is the current page:

```
<%= link_to_unless_current("Index", :action => 'index') { link_to("Index", {:action => 'index'}, {:class => 'current' }) %>
<%= link_to_unless_current("Account", :action => 'account') { link_to("Account", {:action => 'account'}, {:class => 'current' }) %>
<%= link_to_unless_current("Payments", :action => 'payments') { link_to("Payments", {:action => 'payments'}, {:class => 'current' }) %>
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 2):

You can define an additional helper method, that would be calling [link_to_unless_current](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_unless_current):

```
def link_to_current_with_class(name, current_class, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
  link_to_unless_current(name, options, html_options) do
    options[:class] = current_class + " " + options[:class]
    link_to(name, options, html_options)
  end
end
```

and then call it from you navigation partial:

```
<%= link_to_current_with_class "Index", "current", "/dashboard/index" %>
```